# Data validation in Excel with IF and range of numbers

Tags: excel

I need to create a budgeting file in which managers are supposed to evaluate employee performance.
In BB column I have a performance type, BC column bonus assignment rule and in BD column manager is supposed to insert what percentage of bonus should be assigned. So if e.g. employee has high performance manager can assign bonus between 5-10%, and it could be 8%. I am trying to create data validation rule for BD, which will allow manager to assign bonus only from the correct range of numbers.

Edit for more context: Once the manager asses employee for "Average performance", then manager can give bonus between 0-2%; once manager type e.g. 4%, excel will not allow for such action, as it is not matching with the data validation rule. I want column BD to have data validation setup, so that it will not allow manager to give more than 0-2% with the "Average performance" and similar with others performance rates. I was trying with IFS, but it is gives me errors [screenshot from the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga4qi.png)

Trying with IFS but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

So, use a vlookup like so:

[image]

Notice I only check for the first 3 letters as that is sufficient given the example bands you supplied.

Why did I use the first 3 letters? Since you have typing errors in your own example shown, like the spelling of "Average Perfromance", using just the fist three reduces the liklihood of an error.

Vlookup() finds the exact match and returns the value, you can then calculate with that result, either in the cell or with another cell.

One way of giving the manager discretion is to add an amount to the result of the vlookup - like 1 or 2 or 3%.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your replay. It is not working and I think I may not be clear what I need. Once the manager asses employee for "Average performance", then manager can give bonus between 0-2%; once manager type e.g. 4%, excel will not allow for such action, as it is not matching with the data validation rule. I want column BD to have data validation setup, so that it will not allow manager to give more than 0-2% with the "Average performance" and similar with others performance rates.

Comment: @KamilaŁazuka then add an extra table or cell so the manager can provide a "top up" as needed as I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would first put the upper and lower values in separate columns, and then use an `IF` statement with `INDEX & MATCH` to check the numbers fall between your ranges.

Example:

`= IF(AND( AY6 >= INDEX(BC4:BC9,MATCH(AX6,BB4:BB9)), AY6 <= INDEX(BD4:BD9,MATCH(AX6,BB4:BB9))), "YES", "NO")`

[image: Excel]

`=IF(AND "YES", "NO"` Checks that the bonus is between the two values and puts "YES" or "NO" in the cell

`AY6 >= INDEX(BC4:BC9,MATCH(AX6,BB4:BB9))` Checks the bonus is greater than lower limit

`AY6 <= INDEX(BD4:BD9,MATCH(AX6,BB4:BB9))` Checks the bonus is less than high limit